# How do I make redirection dynamic

Tags: php, redirect, header

Please i need your help with a small issue i'm having. I'm using the Redirecting users to the page they have just pasted a comment on, and **d=3** is suppose to be dynamic i.e take different intergers according to the **id** .

I've tried to add the php variable like this

```
 Header('Location: http://site/a.php?id=$articleID')
```

but i get an error.

```
 Header('Location: http://site/a.php?id=3')
```

Please how can I get over this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass variables into single quoted strings

```
header("Location: http://site/a.php?id=$articleID");
exit;
```

don't forget to include `exit;`, otherwise the rest of the script will still execute until the new page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Change your quotes from single to double. Single quotes won't interpret variables inside them.

```
 Header("Location: http://site/a.php?id=$articleID")
```